# How to run cucumber file from command line

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have cucumber feature file located at below location on my local:

```
C:\ProjectWork\Workspace\Cucumber\DIT_Cucumber\src\cucumber\featureOne.feature
```

and Junit jar at below location:

```
C:\DurgeshProjectWork\Workspace\JarFiles\junit-4.11.jar
```

When I have tried several commands like below to execute the feature file from command prompt however all the time getting same error as

```
Could not fine class
```

Below are the commands which I used:
Command 1:

```
C:\>java -cp C:\ProjectWork\Workspace\JarFiles\junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore C:\DurgeshProjectWork\Workspace\Cucumbe
r\DIT_Cucumber\bin\cucumber\featureOne.feature
```

Command 2:

```
C:\ProjectWork\Workspace\Cucumber\DIT_Cucumber\src\cucumber>java -cp C:\ProjectWork\Workspace\JarFiles\junit-4.11.jar org
.junit.runner.JUnitCore featureOne.feature
```

Could you please help me to run this feature file from command line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI Team,  Any suggestions??????? I haven't received any reply on it yet. thanks!

Answer (score 15):

**JUnit Approach**

If using JUnit, you can run the test the same way you would run a JUnit test on the command line:

```
java -cp <classpath> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.example.test.RunCukesTest
```

where `RunCukesTest` is the unit test that sets all the cucumber options, e.g.:

```
package com.example.test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "json:target/report.json")
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

**Cucumber-jvm Approach**

You can also use cucumber-jvm on the command line:

```
java -cp <classpath> cucumber.api.cli.Main \
   --glue com.example.test \
   --plugin pretty path/to/features
```

**Maven**

The challenge in both previous cases is to build the classpath and make sure all the dependencies are properly loaded, including your own classes and the feature files.  An easier solution would be to use for example [Maven to define all the deps](https://github.com/tychobrailleur/cucumber-jvm-examples/blob/master/java-example/pom.xml); running the tests is then as simple as:

```
mvn verify
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed info, can you please clarify how to do with gradle as well ? gradle is replacing maven and it will be nice to include it as well in the answer. Thanks, Vikram

Comment: Hi, what about using `cucumber.options` from command line without maven? Do you know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber with Java:

Run Feature:
`java -cp "jars/*" cucumber.api.cli.Main -p pretty features`

compile Step Definition file:
`javac -cp "jars/*" step_definition/StepDef.java`

Run Scenario:
`java -cp "jars/*;." cucumber.api.cli.Main -p pretty -g step_definition features`

Comment: Here features is directory of feature files and step_definition is a directory of Step Definition files.

Comment: how to specify multiple --tags option with multiple tags?