# Cucumber `--tags` options from command line?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

What i would like to do is to pass cucumber options from command line to execute scenarios with tag name @extecuteThese but also i wanted to exclude scenarios that are with tag name @WIP so what am i doing so far is

```
-Dcucumber.options='--tags @executeThese --tags ~@WIP'
```

But unfortunately, it's not considering ~@WIP tag option

Any help, much appreciated!!

Comment: That looks right to me. Could there be something you missed, like case of the @WIP?

Comment: If you could include how your scenarios are tagged, that would be helpful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lets pretend this is your feature:

```
Feature ABC

@executeThese
Scenario: abc1

@WIP @executeThese
Scenario: abc2
```

What you are currently doing is equivalent to an `AND` operation. so only `abc2` will be run

In order to run both you need to do an `OR` operation equivalent to do this run:

`cucumber -t @WIP,@executeThese`
This will run `abc1` and `abc2`

If you want to execute all that are `@executeThese` But Not `@WIP` you need to do this:

`cucumber -t @executeThese -t ~@WIP`

This will run `abc1` only

Comment: Thanks @Mo H. The scenario which failing is for me is `cucumber -t @execute1,execute2 -t ~@WIP`

Comment: You need to be consistent about how you reference the tags in your command line. In your comment you do this in 3 different ways (@tag, tag and ~@tag). Everything you need is in the help if you read it carefully (cucumber --help, look at the -t section)

Comment: You can call Cucumber from the command line? 
Unfair!  I can't.
However, I can call Cucumber through Maven:
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="–-tags @MyTaggedScenarioName" 
BTW, thanks a million for the -t hint.  I was able to look at the man page by doing:
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="–help"

Comment: @Tihamer Yes you can actually with java aswell! Although not how I've shown it, i've used cucumber with ruby and it gives you a nice CLI. If you wanna do it with java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586937/how-to-run-cucumber-file-from-command-line. 

I'm glad that this answer is still helping people :)

Comment: Thanks, but it turned out that going through maven was *way* too slow. But your hint gave me the idea of calling cucumber directly from Java: as in cucumber.api.cli.Main.  Turned out a bit tricky, but it was easier than overwriting the CucumberOption annotations.

Comment: @Tihamer can you elaborate? What part was slow?

Answer (score 7):

Use this command

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@executeThese and not @WIP"
```

This will execute @executeThese tag ignoring @WIP. You can find several variation of Cucumber command line [here](https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/cucumber-java-command-line-ignore-or-skip-scenario-or-feature)