# passing multiple tags thought maven command line

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

kind of stuck here-
I can pass a single tag through maven command line like so-

mvn clean -Dcucumber.options="--tags @runThis"

However, I am unable to pass multiple tags through.
any help would be much appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the call that fails and give the error message.

Comment: command passed- mvn clean -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tag1 --tags @tag2"                      
      response optained-" None of the features at [classpath:] matched the filters: [@tag1, @tag2]"

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841594/cucumber-tags-options-from-command-line

Comment: @Ranjith's .I missed this one dude! my bad. thanks for pointing that to me.

Answer (score 1):

If want to run scenario with **tag_1 and tag_2**

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tag_1 --tags @tag_1"
```

and if you want to run scenario with **tag_1 or tag_2**

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tag_1,@tag_2"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude. As Rajnith's mentioned , this question is an un-necessary duplication. my bad.