# Can we change the order of execution of cucumber scenarios?

Tags: java, testing, automation, cucumber, testng

I want to execute testcases in below order.
Example: execution starts with 3rd scenario of 2nd feature then 4th scenario of 6th feature and so on.

Can we do this customization using TestNG/cucumber options/java or any other tool?

Is it possible using hooks or cli options --order ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this with use of @tags above the above the line that has the Scenario keyword.  Then execute multiple test runs but using the tag options as [parameters passed to the build as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841594/cucumber-tags-options-from-command-line).

However, this approach does seem a little odd.  If the reasons for doing this are to force an order due to tests leaving data cached in the running application that require state from the other one then this is not good practice.   Each Scenario should be completely runnable in isolation and without any prior one that might set up state.