# Fetching Tag from excel sheet and trying to pass the same tag in cucumber options in cucumber framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

I am trying to fetch the desired tag and pass it in cucumber option  in cucumber framework where tag is stored in excel sheet.I am done with the coding to fetch the desired tag from Excel(ExcelReader Class).But not able to pass the same tag in the cucumber options in the Runner class. Can you please help me on this.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBZ1Q.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHkNR.jpg)

I am not getting a proper solution to pass the variable "tag" in cucumber options so that i can trigger the same respective testcases with the tag which is there in the Excel sheet.

Comment: Please post your code and don't post images.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the tags directly to the `runner` class. When you run the `junit` `runner` class, before executing any code, it loads all `cucumber.options` so parameterizing the `tags` in `runner` class is not possible. You can pass tags from command line, please refer this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841594/cucumber-tags-options-from-command-line).

Alternatively you can use `junit.runner.JUnitCore` to execute the `junit` classes. Let's see an example,

**Step#1**:  You need to have a `main` method to execute the code as java program not as junit test.

```
import org.junit.internal.TextListener;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("cucumber.options", "--tags @Login"); //You can use the tag what you are reading from excel here.
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
        junit.run(Runner.class);
    }
}
```

**Step#2**: Remove `tags` option from `Runner` class.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src\\test\\resources\\Features", glue = { "code" })
public class Runner {

}
```

**Step#3**: Run your `main` method.

**Feature file**:

```
Feature: Application

  @Login
  Scenario: Login
    Given Login to the application

  @Logout
  Scenario: Login
    Given Logout from the application
```

**Step definition**:

```
public class StepDefs {

    @Given("^Login to the application$")
    public void login() {
        System.out.println("Logged into the application");
    }

    @Given("^Logout from the application$")
    public void logout() {
        System.out.println("Logged out from the application");
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Logged into the application

1 Scenarios ([32m1 passed[0m)
1 Steps ([32m1 passed[0m)
0m0.477s
```