# automatically run external application, which use Cucumber for testing main application

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, teamcity

We have application which use Cucumber framework for testing our second application, the applications runs on own processes (black box testing), currently we do following steps:

1) Run DB

2) Run main application

3) Run test application which use Cukumber framework for testing main application

**Question is: how we can do this automatically by using TeamCity ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a **Command Line** build step:

[image]

1. Point to the working directory
2. Run your Cucumber tests from the command line. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30620936/4775223).

[Here is more info on Cucumber's CLI.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_command_line_options.htm)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to write a script that sets up all dependencies. I.e. starting the database, starting the second application and then run the Cucumber stuff. The script would be possible to run on the CI server, i.e. TeamCity or on a developers system so it is easy verify that they didn't break anything before committing.

Restricting the execution to TeamCity only would not be my preferred approach.

This lead toa solution taht depends on your dev and CI environment. Are you running on Windows or on Linux? The scripts will different depending on the operating system.